# Can we use the relational operator in gsub?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I need to replace the `.` character with `. \n` in the following string format. But, the constraint is, don't replace the `.` character with `.\n` in following pattern string only.

```
"test was done and was negative. Urine dipstick: ph = 6\\n \\342\\200\\242 spec. Grav.  = 1.015"
```

I need the following output, like

```
"test was done and was negative. \n Urine dipstick: ph = 6\\n \\342\\200\\242 spec. Grav.  = 1.015"
```

The constraint is => `"spec. Grav.  = 1.015"`.

Comment: "\n" is not the same as '\n'. YOu need to be careful about that. I fixed it.

Comment: @sawa I think you changed the meaning of the question quite significantly. Check your first sentence against the input/expected output. Rolling back in the meantime.

Comment: @Jakub The original sentence was not easy to understand. Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str.gsub(/\.(?! (Grav| =))/, ".\n")
```

should do the job.

#### Brief explanation

- `\.` matches any `.`
- `(?!)` denotes a negative look-ahead. That means that it won't match anything found in these brackets.
- `(Grav| =)` hence a dot followed by either `Grav` or `=` won't be matched.

Comment: Thanks Jakub Hampl. This is not working for me. i.e it's not give the output what i need?. I need the output "test was done and was negative.\nUrine dipstick : ph = 6\\n \\342\\200\\242 spec. grav. = 1.015". Not like this "test was done and was negative.\nUrine dipstick : ph = 6\\n \\342\\200\\242 spec.\ngrav.\n= 1.015". DONT replace the (.) in this passage "spec. grav. = 1.015"

Comment: Didn't really test. Turns out that the negative look-behinds don't work. I edited t to now use negative look-ahead which now properly works.

Comment: No problem. Remember to click the accept button (the check mark to the left of an answer) on answers that solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "test was done and was negative. Urine dipstick: ph = 6\\n \\342\\200\\242 spec. Grav.  = 1.015"

puts str.sub('. ', ".\n") 

#=> test was done and was negative.
#=> Urine dipstick: ph = 6\n \342\200\242 spec. Grav.  = 1.015
```

String.sub only substitutes the first match.

Answer (score 0):

You want this?

```
str.gsub(/\.(?!\n)/, "\.\n")
```